# failure npm run start

Tags: node.js, parsing, parse-platform, npm

Im fairly new to node and Im having an issue migrating a parse DB. When `npm install` and then attempting to `npm run` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server-example
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/DimasImac/Documents/Development/Parse/npm-debug.log
Dimas-Imac:Parse DimasImac$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What I usually do first in such a situation: delete the *node_modules* folder and then run *npm i*.

Comment: what error do you get when you run `node index.js` ?

Comment: assuming entry point of your project is `index.js` file ?

Comment: Correct.  Index.js is entry point

Comment: @AJS I have not tried this command. All I have been doing is opening index.js in text edit, adding my mongo uri, and changing my appid and hitting save. Once I make any change I get this error when trying to npm  run start

Comment: @AJS when running node index.js I get the following: /Users/dimasretinambp/Documents/Development/Parse/index.js:8
var databaseUri = mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds157667.mlab.com:57667/cypdb;
                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :....

Comment: you need to quote the databaseUri. `var databaseUri = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds157667.mlab.com:57667/cypd‌​b"` notice how the string is in quotes.  The second problem yo have is that username and password is not set.  You need to create user of the databse in the mlab ui and then put the username and password in where the `<username>:<password>` are in the uri.

Comment: Hey Arthur, thanks for the response. The <username> and passwords were just placeholders for stackoverflow, so as to not give out the creds. The issue was that I was editing the server on textedit and not using ASCII quotation marks. Once i edited the server on another text editor it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It was a minor but headache inducing issue. While editing the server to add my appID and Server URI i was using TextEdit on the Mac. 
Text Edit does not use ASCII quotation marks <"> but the curly kind. I opened the server in another editor and it worked fine. Now i am able to start the server and query into it.